Is mind-body dualism necessary for mathematical Platonism?
I'm asking whether mathematical Platonism can exist without mind-body dualism because Platonism posits that mathematical objects are abstract, non-physical entities that exist independently of human minds. If our brains, governed by physical laws, can somehow access these abstract objects, it raises the question of whether dualism is necessary to explain this interaction. Without mind-body dualism, it seems unclear how purely physical brains could connect with a non-physical realm, which leads me to wonder if a non-dualistic explanation for Platonism is feasible.
Is mind-body dualism necessary for mathematical Platonism?
If yes, would that imply that reality consists of at least three distinct substances:

the physical,
the mental,
and the Platonic realm?


For context, see:

Since mathematicians are physical beings, does this mean that mathematics ultimately reduces to physics?
If mathematical platonism is true, how do biological brains governed by physical laws access eternal platonic mathematical truths?
If the Platonic world exists how would we know?


Your closing para is more or less Penrose' 3 worlds

Popper has similar. I prefer Penrose.

Yes, the original setting of platonism was straight idealism. The physical/sensible was simply a degenerate derivative of the ideal (forms) and there is no problem with it affecting its derivatives, including by inducing laws of physics. Many other forms of idealism have been offered since, so there is no need for dualistic metaphysics with mind and matter as independent entities.

I would say that there is dualism, but it is not necessarily mind-body-dualism or at least mind-body is not the most accurate label.
I believe a better label for the fundamental dualism would be energy-information-dualism.
Everything physical consists of energy, matter is a form of energy. Everything mental and everything abstract is information.
The mind is not the other substance. The mind is just the brain's ability to process information.

Interesting insight — thanks! Most CSists don't know/remember that The Bit on which so much of their field is based comes not from  engineering OR math but information theory

Agreed. See this answer to the OP's prior question. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/117598/29339 Physics is matter-energy/abstraction dualism, so the interaction is assumed from the start.  But consciousness is not needed for physics.  Only for the rest of life.  The next question should presume your dualism, then ask about consciousness.

Not only is this merely the author's personal opinion, and explicitly so, without any reference or argument to support it, it does not even answer OP's question, that was specifically about Plato's views. How on earth is this the most voted answer?

I did answer the question: Mind-body dualism is not necessary. Answers should be judged based on whether they contribute and make sense, not by whose ideas they are. Original thinking should be encouraged and evaluated and not bluntly dismissed.

It's not what OP was asking for. When people explicitly ask for references about Plato, references about Plato are expected. It shouldn't be that hard to figure out. If I ask what the Weather Forecast Office says the weather will be and you answer "I think it's gonna rain", you are not answering the question. Original thinking is welcome when it's supported by an argument, mere opinions are not "thinking". When you don't know there is no shame is abstaining from replying, quite the opposite.

@armand I don't see an explicit request for references about Plato in the question. I was under the impression that Platonism isn't just about Plato. Kind of like when someone asks about Newtonian physics, it doesn't mean they are asking about Newton. I'm not saying I agree with this answer but just that I'm a little unsure of that specific complaint.

@JimmyJames note that there aren't any reference to platonism either in this answer. Actually  there are no reference to anything. So, what exactly is the point of your objection? The quality of answers has been going down severely as of late, as people who don't know better answer happily with their unsupported opinions tossed around in about 10 lines of text - which is contrary to the site's policy -, and people who know even less upvote those poor answers. Fair criticism is the only thing that can improve the overall quality of the site.

@armand "note that there aren't any reference to platonism either in this answer" That seems to be a more valid complaint. I just think if we are going to start arguing about what is and isn't a good or valid answer, we should be clear about what the criteria are.

@JimmyJames like every SE, this SE has guidelines where the expected standard of quality for answers is documented. Namely, mere personal opinions are not welcome. Feel free to give it a look, it will save you some time rather than making pointless objections defending the references to platonism of an answer that contains none...

@armand I never defend "the references to platonism".  I just noted there was no request for references to Plato in the question.  Feel free to take a look.

Synthesizing an answer from a bunch of Conifold comments on (P/p)latonism from

here (an old one)
here (this question)
here (from a few days ago)

with some suitable rephrasing and reordering and (parenthesized) commentary:

Modern platonists (note small ‘p’) are not Platonists (capital ‘P’). And abstract objects (in the modern eg. SEP sense) are not Platonic forms (I’ve changed Conifold’s ‘p’ to ‘P’) Plato's animated forms are deemed too magical and metaphorical to be taken at face value today. (I agree with the ‘magical’ not the ‘metaphorical’ — I believe most modern platonists treat Plato's magic/mysticism as metaphor. This is developed further below)
So... yes, the original (Plato's) setting of Platonism (Conifold's ‘p’ → ‘P’) was straight idealism. The physical/sensible was simply a degenerate derivative of the ideal (forms) and there is no problem with it affecting its derivatives, including by inducing laws of physics. Many other forms of idealism have been offered since, so there is no need for dualistic metaphysics with mind and matter as independent entities.

Benacerraf’s Dilemma

Most modern platonists, unlike Plato, do not envision a separate platonic realm and see mathematical (and other abstract) objects as perceptual and/or conceptual aspects of our ordinary "realm" accessed through various abstraction procedures, see IEP

As I understand it Benacerraf's dilemma applies to modern platonism not to Plato's original, the crucial difference between the two being that the platonist's forms are inert and non-causal unlike Plato who believed them to be the primal reality.
Why Plato is hard on the modern reader
Post Plato, the western world has been more Aristotelian than Platonic.
While Plato focused on the realm of ‘forms’ (unsatisfactory translation of eidos) as the ultimate reality, Aristotle shifted the focus to the material world and the nature of objects within it. He argued that objects are composed of two essential elements: substance and form.

Substance: This refers to the underlying amorphous matter or material composition of an object.
Form: This is the organizing principle or essence that gives an object its specific characteristics and defines what it is.

Aristotle believed that the form and matter of an object are inseparable and together constitute its essence.
Crucially, for Aristotle neither form alone nor substance alone is properly causal.  This has become the default view from Aristotle on.
So Plato's Ideation is the light whose shadows are the material world looks too kooky/spooky to be taken seriously.
In short, even if we are reading Plato, we read him with Aristotelian eyes.

You ask:

Is mathematical Platonism possible without mind-body dualism?

Yes. I've never seen anyone claim that Platonic thinking requires mind-body dualism, and I don't believe any compelling argument exists it does. If we take a look at the IEP's article on mathematical Platonism (IEP), in fact, we find no mention of dualism at all. Why might this be? Because Platonic thinking largely leans on the idea that mathematical structure and objects is independent of human thought entirely. Thus, it would be contradictory to claim such a thesis and then require some property of the mind to be a requirement. From the IEP:

Platonists argue—or, more frequently, simply assume—that the best explanation of this objectivity is that mathematical theories have a subject matter that is quite independent of rational beings and their activities. The Independence Thesis is a standard way of articulating the relevant type of independence.

Mind-body dualism (IEP), as well, has no ontological commitment to mathematical realism. The default position in mathematical philosophy that does have commitments between mathematical activity and the mind is another position entirely. L.E.J Brouwer was an advocate of mathematical intuitionism (SEP). Here we see some form of dependence, in contradiction to mathematical realism, between abstract objects and the mind. From the SEP:

Intuitionism is a philosophy of mathematics that was introduced by the Dutch mathematician L.E.J. Brouwer (1881–1966). Intuitionism is based on the idea that mathematics is a creation of the mind. The truth of a mathematical statement can only be conceived via a mental construction that proves it to be true, and the communication between mathematicians only serves as a means to create the same mental process in different minds.


"Why might this be? Because Platonic thinking largely leans on the idea that mathematical structure and objects is independent of human thought entirely" - But then how are physical brains able to have epistemic access to non-physical abstract Platonic objects, if they don't have a non-physical component that can interact with such a realm, which sounds a lot like mind-body dualism?

@user80226 you might like Mark Balaguer’s proposed method of access: there are so many mathematical (platonic) objects that we can’t avoid thinking about them. Not that we hold the exact abstract objects in our minds, but we think about non-abstract correlates by our human brains. He calls this full-blooded Platonism and is his way to solve the access problem

@user80226 No idea. My position is that mathematical realism is a misunderstanding. I'm an intuitionist, and mathematics is best described as an intersubjective and constructive activity. In fact, I also lean heavily towards instrumentalism and contemporary conceptualism. I think "real" is a very abused term.

No.
The brain thinking about math concepts could – conceptionally – be equivalent to a computer running its programs. The physical matter of the brain is completely and utterly separate from whatever it is it is thinking about; the same as a computer (the physical hardware, electricity and such) has nothing whatsoever to do with the software and data it is working with.
The latter is, in both cases, information. Information is physically real in the sense that you can figure out where it is stored or processed (i.e., in the synapses and the complicate chemical processes going on there; or in the transistors and basic storage elements within a computer).  If it is written big enough, you can see it.
Information, like other structural elements (i.e., the exact ordering of more basic physical elements – think lego blocks), is pure physics; you can describe it, recreate it, destroy it and so on and forth; you do not need some kind of invisible, unseeable, unprovable, unfathomable dualism for it.
N.B. this answer does not pose or require that there actually is no dualism. It just explains why abstract concepts can be thought about (or calculated) without requiring dualism.
